_textPainter.textScaler = TextScaler.linear(textScaleFactor); can anyone tell me what is and how to clear this type of error in flutter
When i trying creating an calender for my app in flutter
_textPainter.textScaler = TextScaler.linear(textScaleFactor);
i got like error when I installed the package in pubspec.yaml (syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^25.1.38) .Can anyone explain it what is this how to rectify this kind of error.
I need solution of it.
